# Can I call a filter on all Rich Text fields?

Tags: redactor, richtext, replace

I'm looking to dynamically replace the ℠ glyph with `<sup>SM</sup>` in all rich text fields, since that glyph doesn't exist in the font we're using. I'd like to avoid having to call the `|replace` filter on every field in every template, and I can't seem to get the `customAsciiCharMappings` general config setting to work either (I'm not sure if I really understand what it does). Does Craft have something like a global replace function/filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customAsciiCharMappings` won't help you here.

There is the "Find and Replace" tool available to admins (Settings->Tools) in the Control Panel, but its' a one-off thing and searches/replaces against *all* textual field types (Plain Text, Rich Text, etc. both inside and outside of Matrix fields).

Honestly, probably just create a small Twig macro that wraps `|replace` and use that wherever you're outputting Rich Text fields on the site.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm not sure the macro would be more convenient than manually wrapping them all in `|replace` but that looks like the best way.